# Getting a Constant key size using a crypto-graphy Algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, algorithm

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and Sql server 2008

I am new to Cryptography.
I need to encrypted module names into a key. and after the key is given to the 
customer the encrypted data should be able to retrieve the module name from the key.

I have to make CD-key pattern of key. which has some data encrypted inside it.

I need to have a constant size of key.
What is the best algorithm for this kind of specification.

Please help me out.

Comment: if your down voting some one just let him known y? so that he can improvise on it.

Comment: Your question is based on so many mistaken assumptions. I'm trying to figure out where to start with an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't approach cryptography this way. It just doesn't work. You need to start with precise requirements, a threat model, and so on. What you have is just the end result you desire and you can't design from that. Secure and insecure solutions both produce the same result, the difference is in how they respond to threats.